# How to curl -R to preserve file time?

Tags: curl, ftp

When I use `curl -R` to download a file from an FTP server, it seems that the time is not the same on the server and on the local machine.

```
$ lftp -e 'rels -l usa.txt;exit'  -u 'shortstock:' ftp://ftp3.interactivebrokers.com
-rw-r--r--    1 ftp      ftp       1232043 Mar 09 19:15 usa.txt
$ curl -R -O -s -u 'shortstock:' ftp://ftp3.interactivebrokers.com/usa.txt
$ TZ=America/New_York stat -c %w$'\n'%x$'\n'%y$'\n'%z usa.txt
2022-03-09 14:15:31.000000000 -0500
2022-03-09 14:15:31.000000000 -0500
2022-03-09 14:15:31.000000000 -0500
2022-03-09 19:28:14.620714215 -0500
```

How can I get the local version have the same time as the server version?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that’s not possible being the two machines and I think the mtime?

Answer (score 0):

The times are the same.

The files on the server GMT and your system appears to be America/New_York, which is currently 5 hours behind GMT. 14:15 in New York (-0500) is the same time as 19:15 (-0000) as displayed using *your* local time zone.

EDIT:

**Example**

```
lftp -e 'rels -l usa.txt;exit'  -u 'stockdown:' ftp://ftp3.interactivebrokers.com
-rw-r--r--    1 ftp      ftp       1207583 Mar 13 12:15 usa.txt 

curl -R -O -s -u 'stockdown:' ftp://ftp3.interactivebrokers.com/usa.txt

TZ=America/Los_Angeles stat -c %w$'\n'%x$'\n'%y$'\n'%z usa.txt
-
2022-03-13 05:15:30.000000000 -0700
2022-03-13 05:15:30.000000000 -0700
2022-03-13 09:23:22.370307478 -0700

TZ=America/New_York stat -c %w$'\n'%x$'\n'%y$'\n'%z usa.txt
-
2022-03-13 08:15:30.000000000 -0400
2022-03-13 08:15:30.000000000 -0400
2022-03-13 12:23:22.370307478 -0400

TZ=GMT stat -c %w$'\n'%x$'\n'%y$'\n'%z usa.txt
-
2022-03-13 12:15:30.000000000 +0000
2022-03-13 12:15:30.000000000 +0000
2022-03-13 16:23:22.370307478 +0000
```

Comment: I am confused. Is the epoch time relative to UTC time? Isn't that in my local machine, the first three lines of stat output should be 19:15:31.000000000?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. The last line is the "change time", which is when it was downloaded because curl changed the access and modification times to match the one from the server *after* the transfer completes. There is no notion of "creation time" with Unix files. I think the "modify" time is the one you really care about. That time is when the file was created (if it has never been modified), or the time it was last modified.

Comment: But all three times are the same. I think all three should be 19:15:31.000000000

Comment: with `TZ=GMT ...` they will all be 19:15:31. curl preserved the time, but the server is displaying the time as 19:15 GMT, and your machine 14:15 EST which is 4 hours behind GMT.

Comment: No. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: That's odd. What OS and curl version do you have? In your original post, the times look correct but I don't know why `stat` displays the same times when different TZ's are set. I updated the answer with example output from my system which shows the times changing as expected.

Comment: I thought your were referring to curl as the question is about curl. But you used TZ for stat. So the mystery is solved.